# How to convert nose test into py.test porting nose-testconfig ini file

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, nose

I was thinking about changing unit test framework in a legacy project with thousand of tests. Most of this test have an ini configuration file using nose-testconfig plugin, I read a lot of good things of py.test unit test framework so I would like to know if it possible to change between frameworks easily and quickly. And as we are using pycharm, I think py.test is much more compatible with pycharm than nosetests.

Any idea about of this? In ini file there is just some attribute tags and variables information "inside" this tags, nothing else.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/nose.html)?